# Oracle 12C silent installation - response file

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I am installing Oracle 12c using a response file. The installer exits after a while, with the following error message:

`ERROR: Cannot add user to application access ACL. No mapping between account names and security IDs was done (534)`

The installer exits but Oracle 12c *partially* installs. When I open SQL Plus, I get the error message:

`ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error`

I don't have these problems with a manual installation, only using the response file.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How did you create the response file? Perhaps this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792726/install-oracle-client-from-command-line-without-user-interaction

Comment: It's important to add o/s details